# DocFX configuration setting to override default max directory depth?

Tags: docfx

In DocFX configuration (e.g., docfx.json), is it possible to override this max directory depth setting that appears to default to five (5)?

While running a DocFX build, I'm getting a couple output lines complaining about some web font assets being too deep in the directory structure.

> The following directories exceed max allowed depth 5, ignored: dist/assets/fonts/web/courier,dist/assets/fonts/web/futura,dist/assets/fonts/web/futuracon,dist/assets/fonts/web/mrseaves,dist/assets/fonts/web/wavehaus.

### Investigation

In searching the DocFX code, I [found this message in the **LocalFileResourceReader.cs** file's `GetFiles` method](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DocAsCode.Build.Engine/ResourceFileReaders/LocalFileResourceReader.cs#L55). And it appears that this aligns with the `5` depth in the message with a [`const int MaxSearchLevel = 5` at the top of the file](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DocAsCode.Build.Engine/ResourceFileReaders/LocalFileResourceReader.cs#L10). In the constructor for that class, there is an optional `maxSearchLevel` parameter that defaults to that const if the argument isn't provided.

```cs
public LocalFileResourceReader(string directory, int maxSearchLevel = MaxSearchLevel)
{ ... }
```

I haven't cloned the repo to properly track references, but GitHub's own symbol tracking suggests the only place that `LocalFileResourceReader` constructor is called is in [**TemplateManager.cs** where it is called with a single parameter](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DocAsCode.Build.Engine/TemplateProcessors/TemplateManager.cs#L37). This seems to imply that overriding the maximum search level isn't allowed, but I'm hoping that's not the case.

```cs
private CompositeResourceReader CreateTemplateResource(IEnumerable<string> resources)
{
    return new(GetTemplateDirectories(resources).Select(path => new LocalFileResourceReader(path)));
}
```

Additionally, searching the [DocFX JSON reference](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/reference/docfx-json-reference.html) doesn't seem to offer any mention of the word "depth".